# JPA Error joining table and view

Tags: jpa

I need to join a table and a view in a JPA query.  The query won't compile because the view columns can't be identified.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**Updated with parent entity and consistent naming**

The query is:

```
select count(m.id) 
    from MultiSpeedMotor m, 
        MultiSpeedQuery q1  
    where m.id = q1.motorId 
        and q1.power = 10
```

The errors are:

```
The state field path 'q1.motorId' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
The state field path 'q1.power' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

I am working with a legacy database that has a denormalized table similar to this

```
Long motorId 
Long id  
Double hi_power 
Double lo_power
```

I have used a view with a union query to normalize this table into

```
Long motorId  
Long id 
Long hi 
Double power
```

To model the view of union query in JPA, I have used an @IdClass

```
public class MultiSpeedQueryId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7996931190943239257L;

    private Long motorId;
    private Long id;
    private Long hi;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "multi_speed_query")
@IdClass(MultiSpeedQueryId.class)
public class MultiSpeedQuery implements IMultiSpeedQuery {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "motor_id")
    private Long motorId;
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Id
    private Long hi;

    private Double power;
    ...
}
```

The parent Entity is mapped as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "multi_speed_motor")
public class MultiSpeedMotor implements Serializable, IMultiSpeedMotor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3019928176257499187L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the following works: `... WHERE q1.motor = m ...` and replace `MultiSpeedQuery.motorId` with the actual `MultiSpeedMotor motor`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are suggesting.  The q1 and m are standard JPA alias.

Comment: According to your table def there while there is a parentId column, there is no motorId .. does this actually exist in the db ? If so the actual table definitions for both tables would be helpful

Comment: I updated the original post to use the actual field name motorId in the explanation instead of parentId.  I used parentId originally in the explanation to better indicate the role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is correct as written.

You CAN join Entities with no pre-defined relationship by using the syntax.

```
where a.id = b.joinField
```

The issue was much simpler.  I missed part of the JPA error log that was telling the real problem.

```
The abstract schema type 'MultiSpeedQuery' is unknown.
```

Once I added the Entity to the persistence.xml, the query, as originally written, worked perfectly.